# Client error while Stopping instances using lambda in environmental variables

Tags: python, instance, boto3

I am getting client error to stop the instance using Lambda providing instance id in environmental variables but working fine when i hard code the instance id

Lambda Function:

```
instances = ['i-0d66b89b8c010560d']

import boto3
import os
# Enter the region your instances are in. Include only the region without 
specifying Availability Zone; e.g., 'us-east-1'
region = 'us-east-1'
# Enter your instances here: ex. ['X-XXXXXXXX', 'X-XXXXXXXX']
# instances = ['i-0d66b89b8c010560d']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print 'stopping your instance'
    instances = os.environ['INSTANCES_ID']
    print instances
    print type(instances)
    instances = list(instances)
    print type(instances)
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)
```

Log output:

```
START RequestId: 5c965493-fd10-11e8-9c0f-09f0c600ad35 Version: $LATEST
stopping your instance
i-0d66b89b8c010560d
<type 'str'>
<type 'tuple'>
An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling the 
StopInstances operation: Invalid id: "i": ClientError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.Malformed) when calling  
the StopInstances operation: Invalid id: "i"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your Log output, your 'instances' is a str with the value `i-0d66b89b8c010560d`. What you probably do not know, is that str is iterable. Making the list 'call' behave different from what you're expecting. So when you call this code:

```
instances = list(instances)
```

You're actually doing this:

```
>>> instances = 'i-0d66b89b8c010560d'
>>> list(instances)
['i', '-', '0', 'd', '6', '6', 'b', '8', '9', 'b', '8', 'c', '0', '1', '0', '5', '6', '0', 'd']
```

See what happens? Your str is converted to a list with each index of the str being an index in the list.

So the solution would be:

```
instances = ['i-0d66b89b8c010560d']

import boto3
import os
# Enter the region your instances are in. Include only the region without 
specifying Availability Zone; e.g., 'us-east-1'
region = 'us-east-1'
# Enter your instances here: ex. ['X-XXXXXXXX', 'X-XXXXXXXX']
# instances = ['i-0d66b89b8c010560d']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print 'stopping your instance'
    instances = os.environ['INSTANCES_ID']
    print instances
    print type(instances)
    instances = [instances]
    print type(instances)
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'stopped your instances: ' + str(instances)
```